# Prevent "remember password" prompt with e.returnValue

Tags: javascript, html

In my form, I do some client side validation. When I find there are errors, I do `e.returnValue = false; return false;`, however this is still triggering the remember password feature of the browser, screenshot below. It makes sense to me that `e.preventDefault(); e.stopPropagation();` does not block the "remember password" feature, as there are many web apps that need to stop form submiting behavior and handle it via ajax. However I was hoping the `e.returnValue` of false would block that, does anyone know how?

[image]

Comment: If you add the `required` attribute to the required fields and the `novalidate` attribute to the form, does it still show up?

Comment: Thanks @Ryan but the issue is I want the password prompt to happen, but only if there are no errors (due to validation or custom js).

Comment: Dunno how what I said contradicts that. `novalidate` is not `autocomplete="off"`.

Comment: @Ryan, your way works real well but all the validation is out of my control and in the automatic hands of the browser. So when it fails for custom js validation it is still prompting - http://i.imgur.com/hmVnuEE.png - however you are right that it wont prompt if the validation criteria of the browser are not met.

Comment: Even if they’re not enough, you should still make use of `<input type="email">` and `minlength`.

Comment: For the password-matching condition, try [`setCustomValidity`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/HTML5/Constraint_validation#Constraint_API's_element.setCustomValidity())?

Comment: @Noitidart have you tried with google or IE? it seems only FF prob

Answer (score 0):

HI try this in your **form**:

```
<form id="id" action="action.php" method="post" autocomplete="off">
```

**Using Jquery**

```
$('#id').attr('autocomplete', 'off');
```

Comment: Thanks @Amitesh but the issue is I want the password prompt to happen, but only if there are no errors (due to validation or custom js).

Comment: you can use it with condition when want the prompt when don't want the prompt

Comment: Thanks Amitesh, I tried it, but even if the attribute is not dynamically toggled, its still always showing the prompt, is this a bug in the browser maybe?

Comment: Yes it may be .